# How to set uid/gid of volume mounts in docker container

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, docker-container

Can we set uid/gid of volume mounts in a docker container? There is a way in Kubernetes to manage this that is fsgroup ([How to define the uid, gid of a mounted volume in Pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62369296/how-to-define-the-uid-gid-of-a-mounted-volume-in-pod)) but can I do the same in docker and use that with ECS task definition? We can pass a user and group like uid:gid or username:group name in ECS task definition but that only overrides the docker host container user